# Where the heck do you ask certain questions?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, scope, asking-questions

It seems like half the times I have a serious question that I need an answer to it gets down-voted. So obviously people feel these questions shouldn't be there. Other times I get an answer and it gets 3 or 4 votes, maybe even less, sometimes only mine. Whereas the question itself doesn't get any.

So this has raised the question, in my mind, of where the heck do I ask certain questions?

For example this one that I just thought of, however have decided to post here on Meta because I was told by the question title bar NOT to post the question.

> Using C++11, as far as the compiler is concerned when would it be
>   better to use a Lambda vs a Method or Function? For example I have a
>   piece of code right now which is written as a Lambda. If I end up
>   finding a second method which needs to use it would it be acceptable
>   to keep it as a Lambda and maybe even just duplicate it into the
>   second method? Or despite it being a relatively small mathematical
>   function and not so much as even assigning values to variables, would
>   it be better to rewrite it as a method and why would it be better?

Where can such a question exist? I don't have the time to learn specifically how or where to ask questions; I am too busy trying to come up with the questions in the first place. So what should I do or where should I ask this question...or what is the answer to the damn question?!

Comment: *When would it be better to use a Lambda vs a Method or Function?* You may ask that question at your local bar. Sorry, I meant in chat.

Comment: So the C++Lounge?

Comment: "When would it be better" > opinion based so will probably be closed

Comment: What research were you planning do do before asking the question e.g. writing code for each and comparing their performance? What definition of "better" were you planning to use? What compilers/operating systems were you intending to target?

Comment: So I would have to phrase it explicitly around performance? As that is what I care about, whether the CPU would have any benefits.. which given its C basis I would have expected to be implicit..

Comment: As well as include the things Robert has just mentioned..?

Comment: It's also a question where the answer could easily become incorrect in the next release of the targetted compiler. In short it's awfully hard to turn that into a good question even if you tightly define it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No I am not sure whether any CPU would benefit, which is why I would want to ask the question to people who know more about compilers and machine code. So then is the answer to my question that if I have an obscure question I don't know how to answer as just some dumb 27 year old trying to learn as much as he can.. that I shouldn't ask the question for fear of enough down votes to be banned from asking questions? I am not sure if everybody knew that, but that is apparently a thing.

Comment: @RobertLongson So some questions shouldn't be explored, regardless of the interest it might hold?

Comment: They shouldn't be explored **here**. Other non-SE sites might support them.

Comment: @Josh, you were definitely right to ask us here before posting such a question on SO, it would not have been well-received indeed. There is nothing wrong with you wondering about such a question, it's just not suited at all for our format. I also wonder what would come out of eventual answers, if any. I expect dumps of generated assembly code to "prove" such-and-such compiler on such-and-such platform emits different machine code for function and lambda calls, as well as detailed cache locality analysis to estimate benefits. In a few years. And that's the best case.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi , RobertLongson Okay, thanks. That has clarified a few suspicions I've had. That despite SO being so well suited to asking professionals, academics, and experts it isn't well suited for the seeking a breadth of knowledge with the questions asked. Anyways, thanks again. You've been helpful.

Comment: *"Please read past the fury."* - please edit it out before posting.

Comment: this appears to be a strategy question. and i have a different one. strategies are not always obvious, or accessible. so his meta question is really which is the relevant stack exchange site (given there is one for pretty much everything) to ask a strategy question? And maybe another question might be, is there an easy tool to identify a stack exchange site to use (more robust than the listing in the footer)? I dont think this question should be downvoted, its a relevant meta question. the answer is found in the duplicate: www.quora.com

Comment: @jsky hey, thanks for trying to help! Where can I find the "answer" on quora? -- SO can be such a toxic place to try and ask programming related questions. I often find solutions to my problems in questions voted lower than 5. Though half the community acts as though if a question couldn't get 500 upvotes it is worthless having no value to the community.

Answer (score 15):

Stack Overflow is not a suitable place to ask any question under the sun. Questions and their answers need to have lasting value.

It's almost impossible to start from your suggested question and alter it such that it fulfils the criteria of a good question. Even demonstrating prior research such as writing code for each and comparing their performance, and targetting specific compilers/operating systems/versions won't save it as any answers run the risk of becoming out of date with the next compiler release.

Additionally, questions that want to know what is better generally need to define "better", otherwise they run the risk of being closed as opinion based.

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is potentially with your understanding of how the Stack Exchange network works.

> I don't have the time to learn specifically how or where to ask questions; I am too busy trying to come up with the questions in the first place.

Why are you spending any time at all trying to come up with questions?  You *shouldn't* be spending time trying to come up with questions.

As a professional or enthusiast programmer (which is Stack Overflow's target audience), you *should* be spending your programming time trying to **answer** questions.  By this, I do not mean that you should be browsing through unanswered Stack Overflow questions and posting answers to them.  No, I mean that you should be solving programming problems.

You're working on some sort of application to do some sort of something.  Along the way, you'll run into speed bumps.  You'll run into something that prevents you from completing your task at hand.  And now you've very naturally come across a question.

## BUT...

Just because you've come across a question that you need to answer doesn't mean that it's immediately time to sprint to Stack Overflow and post a question.

## NO! STOP!

You're not ready to ask a question yet.

Now it's time to spend some time trying to answer this question.

- What does the official documentation have to say on the subject?
- What do existing Stack Overflow questions have to say on the subject?

There are 9.2 million questions on Stack Overflow.  Many of them have answers.  Are you really so arrogant as to believe that your question (or some variant of your question which has answers good enough to answer your question) hasn't been asked before?  Out of 9.2 million questions to date?

Stack Overflow's goal is not to be a forum with personalized help for personalized problems.  No, rather, it is intended to be resource for professional and enthusiast programmers.  The best way for Stack Overflow to accomplish this is to expect questions to be specific and well researched.

How much research have you put into your question?  How specific is your question?

Comment: It's 9.3 million questions by now. And those are only the non-deleted ones...

Comment: And in another few hours or so it'll be 9.4 million... and this will just continue to prove my point.

Comment: Wow. I am not so arrogant, you certainly appear to be arrogant enough to believe without proper basis that I do not research or attempt to answer my own questions or solve my own problems. That quote you took from my post perfectly demonstrates this as I meant exactly what you went on to say I should do instead.. The arrogance of question answerers on SO is unbelievable

Comment: Then perhaps you should make your questions more clearly demonstrate your research effort. There is not an arrogance about question answerers. Perhaps you perceive this, but your perception is incorrect. This answer is based on a plain-English reading of your question, which apparently, you struggled to make your intentions plainly clear.